# How to change console mode to gui mode in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qmake

I am trying to convert an application  console mode to gui mode but the problem is the console window still appearing with main window.What i want is to hide console window as it dose in gui mode.

.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = cmd
TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG -= console
SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainfile

```
  #include "mainwindow.h"
  #include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The pro looks good... It would be easier to create a new GUI project and copy over source files though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In creator go in `project` under tab `Run Settings` uncheck `Run in terminal`. cmd window will not appear.